# Как узнать размер бара Пуск (Выстота)?

Tags: winapi, vb.net

Как узнать размер бара Пуск (Выстота)?

Comment: Что за бред, зачем Вам это?

Comment: Надо как то сделать чтобы форма не загораживала весь экран

Comment: Есть разрешение экрана и размер рабочего стола.

Вообще, все же лучше предоставлять распределение окон на рабочем столе самому windows, и не вмешиваться в этот не простой процесс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Надо как то сделать чтобы форма не загораживала весь экран

Для определения рабочей области (без системной панели задач) в `Windows` существует свойство `SPI_GETWORKAREA`, значение которого можно получить через вызов [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx).

> SPI_GETWORKAREA
> 0x0030
> Retrieves the size of the work area on the primary display monitor. The work area is the portion of the screen not obscured by the system taskbar or by application desktop toolbars. The pvParam parameter must point to a RECT structure that receives the coordinates of the work area, expressed in virtual screen coordinates.
>
> To get the work area of a monitor other than the primary display monitor, call the GetMonitorInfo function.

Comment: Использовать winapi для того, что можно сделать средствами .net обычно не требуется. А если в данном случае требуется, то было бы неплохо пояснить почему именно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, если Вы можете предложить альтернативу в .net, просто сделайте это в своем ответе.